# I cannot access err.Err from strconv package

Tags: go, error-handling

I am probably missing something really simple here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := "abd"
    fmt.Println(s)
    _, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err))

    fmt.Println(err.Err)

}
```

I am trying to extract the error itself e.g. `ErrSyntax` or `ErrRange`, but I am not able to do so.

After looking at:

https://golang.org/src/strconv/atoi.go?s=3604:3671#L16

I see that `err` is a pointer to `strconv.NumError`

```
    15  // A NumError records a failed conversion.
    16  type NumError struct {
    17      Func string // the failing function (ParseBool, ParseInt, ParseUint, ParseFloat)
    18      Num  string // the input
    19      Err  error  // the reason the conversion failed (ErrRange, ErrSyntax)
    20  }
```

And `Err` is the field that holds either `ErrRange` of `ErrSyntax`. Therefore, I thought that `err.Err` would work, but I get:

```
err.Err undefined (type error has no field or method Err
```

`Err` is public, am I missing something with visibility rules?

What am I missing?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39121749/6169399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get the `*strconv.NumError` value:

```
if e, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError); ok {
    fmt.Println("e.Err", e.Err)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/iWcT61GY6y)