# Go - Handle Errors Conditionally

Tags: go, error-handling

I have a code where I clone multiple gitlab repositories. The library I am depending on is `"gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"`. The clone function will return an error if a repository already exists.

I want to ignore this error and continue the loop of clonning repoistories. Below is my attempt to solve the issue by using `errors.New()` However, it does not work since the returned `err` and the new error do not match.

```golang
import (
   gitgo "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
   "log"
   "errors"

)

var errRepoIsThere = errors.New("repository already exists")

_, err := gitgo.PlainClone(repoLocalPath, false, &gitgo.CloneOptions{})


if !errors.Is(err, errRepoIsThere) {
      log.Fatal(err)
    
}
```

the error returned from `gitgo.PlainClone` is as defined here:

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5#pkg-variables

```golang
ErrRepositoryNotExists = errors.New("repository does not exist")
```

---

I've went through this question
[How to compare Go errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121172/how-to-compare-go-errors) and saw that all awnsers discourage the use of `err.Error() == err2.Error()` type of error handling.

What would be the right approach for my issue in this case?

Comment: `However, it does not work since the returned err and the new error do not match.` _Why_ do you create a new error to begin with? Just use the error the lib uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is a package level var - essentially, a  singleton - so  comparison is appropriate:

```golang
err == gitgo.ErrRepositoryNotExists
```

Comparing `.Error()`  is considered poor practice because error text is incidental (but package exports are assumed reliable)