# golang compare errors returns false, even after using errors.Is() comparison

Tags: go

I am trying to compare an sql error in golang using errors.Is(...) method, which is always returning false.

I have declared an error type variable as below.

```golang
var ErrNoRows = errors.New("no rows in result set")
```

Somewhere down the flow, I am trying to compare an error value with the 'ErrNoRows' error, which always returns false.

However, if I print the err in debug mode, it prints as..

```
(dlv) p err
error(*errors.errorString) *{
        s: "no rows in result set",}
```

and printing ErrNoRows also returns the same thing.

```
(dlv) p ErrNoRows
error(*errors.errorString) *{
        s: "no rows in result set",}
```

But both these objects are not getting equal, when I compare them with Error.Is function.

```
err := tx.QueryRow(ctx, sqlstmt).Scan(&myvar)
if errors.Is(err, ErrNoRows) {
...
}
```

The above check always fails.  What am I doing wrong here?  I am using
https://github.com/jackc/pgx for sql operation.

**EDIT**
I have already seen this question ([How to compare Go errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121172/how-to-compare-go-errors))

The above question talks about using errors.Is(...), instead of a naive equal comparision.  I followed the advice as per that question thread.

I was getting error because of not knowing that I still had to deal with the **same** instances of error objects, as was clarified by @mkopriva.

Comment: Your `ErrNoRows` is a different *instance* of `*errors.errorString` compared to the one returned by `Scan`. It doesn't matter that the string message are the same. The pointer is not the same and therefore the two errors are not considered equal.

Comment: You should compare the error value against the error provided by the package you're using. E.g. if it's `database/sql` then you should use `errors.Is(err, sql.ErrNoRows)`. https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.19.3#ErrNoRows

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/JuYei-4x2Ne (and [this one](https://go.dev/play/p/mtyE5Mrak_U) demonstrates the usefulness of `errors.Is`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582558/golang-compare-errors-returns-false-even-after-using-errors-is-comparison#comment131649831_74582558)'s suggestion, I understand that error objects comparison with the same error instance provided by the original package.

My understanding was that using errors.Is() function might do a deep (attributes comparison), without having to worry about same objects.  But as suggested in the comments, it is not the case.

I had to compare the err returned by calling the sql function, with the err object provided by the same package.

```
err := tx.QueryRow(ctx, sqlstmt).Scan(&myvar)
if errors.Is(err, pgx.ErrNoRows) {
...
}
```